# iOS UI View Switching Button Type

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, view

I would like to make 2 buttons in one of my apps like the following buttons ("Notifications" and "My Stuff"). This is an example from Yik Yak. I have seen this done in many apps. I could make this work on my own but am wondering if there is an official way to accomplish this that has already been setup.
Is there something in the iPhone UI? If so what is it called? I do not need an explanation on how to accomplish this, only the name for the class and can figure it out from there. Thanks.

(The line here slides under the tab tapped and changes the view below)

[image: Yik Yak example for view changing buttons (Notifications and My Stuff)]

Comment: So the question you're asking is: is there a built in function that moves a line between two views/buttons/points? the answer is no. existing libraries will help you to accomplish this, and there might exist a github library as well, but there's no 1 convenience method or class to do what you're asking -- that I know of.

Comment: @LouisTur Alright that answers my question I will just design my own. Thank you.